# Symfony 6 - Override Symfony FormLoginAuthenticator

Tags: authentication, symfony, symfony6

I have to handle multiple type of users on my application

Admin, Teacher, Parent, Student ...etc

Each type of user has it's own table

A user can be a Teacher and a Parent too.[image]

I want to use Symfony `FormLoginAuthenticator`, but instead of sending just login, password and CSRF token, I want to change the login Form to add a `userType` field that tells which user is trying to authenticate.

Is there a way to accomplish this by creating a custom form login authenticator and inheriting the Symfony `FormLoginAuthenticator`, as this one already implements all the necessary functions except handling the new field `userType` that can help retrieve the correct User.?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but a User can have multiple ROLES so why not use ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_STUDENT... to handle this type of behavior?

Comment: Actually every user type is in it's own table. Each user type entity is an usee provider itself

Comment: Person is extended by Admin, Teacher, Student and person holds all common fields - in your case at least username, passwort, roles
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

the only problem may be "user can be teacher and parent" but to be honest - i would use roles for the different groups. the class table inerheitance is use full if you need different fields in your entity types

Comment: Agreed with @Rufinus You should work with Voter for Role based access control